# update-initramfs very slow

Tags: apt, 20.04, kernel, updates, initramfs

I used to just happily `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` often; however, just today, I updated and found the update was hanging for a long time at updating the kernel, specifically at update-initramfs.

The slowdown has been dramatic. It used to take a minute at most to install. Now it can take upwards of an hour or longer. What could be causing this?

Comment: Which CPU do you use?

Comment: 8th gen Intel Core i7-8550U. I decided to load an old backup and that seems to have fixed the problem. Odd.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem, and booting was also very slow (on an older machine). It had to do with compression and the method having changed from gzip to bz.

I eliminated compression altogether by using COMPRESS="cat" in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf and now both building and booting are super fast. (The file name and directory can vary by distro and distro version.)

This fills up more of my /boot directory but it wasn't close to capacity in any case.

Answer (score 3):

I examined this issue too. In Ubuntu 21.10, my `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` had `COMPRESS=zstd` by default, which is a good choice, but unfortunately it doesn't let us configure the compression level. The level is **hardcoded** in `/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs`:

```
case "${compress}" in
#--snip--
zstd)   compress="zstd -q -19 -T0" ;;
```

I changed that -19 to -6, and got it to run in a more sensible time, about 43 seconds to run `update-initramfs -u -k all` with 2 kernel versions installed. It took 150 seconds before the change. The initrd-images grew from about 60 MB to 80 MB as a result, which is a good compromise for me.

Note that `sudo apt autoremove -y` is a good addition to the upgrade command. It removes old unneeded kernels, so it won't spend time processing those.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, things seem to have changed: `zstd)   compress="zstd -q -1 -T0" ;;`

Comment: Fantastic, hopefully they update it like mkinitcpio.conf in ArchLinux where they have `COMPRESSION_OPTIONS`, so you can do like `COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=(-T0 -1)` (for zstd).

Comment: @Stephan Emmy Chow's question still holds for me. I have a 6-core xeon processor with 16GB of ram, and updates on 22.04—particularly `update-initramfs`—are excruciatingly slow compared to past LTS releases, even though the `zstd` compression arguments are just as indicated in your comment on my system.

Comment: @Lexible Do you have `zstd` installed?

Comment: @Stephan Yes I do.